# Quick capture of a specific frame

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, capture

I try to capture video from a file one frame at a specific time or at a certain interval to put it in a string.
I managed to capture images (as jpeg) with opencv and ffmpeg but the problem is that it takes time. I try to send these catches almost in real time between each captured image but there is a slowdown
Currently, between each image in ffmpeg and opencv for each capture, there is 1/2 seconds, which is quite slow.

I have two problems, I do not know how to speed up the capture with opencv (or ffmpeg) and I arrivge in with opencv to the timecode of the frame was captured.

I come with ffmpeg capture a choiced frequency but not with OpenCV.

Would you know how to capture images with OpenCV video of all the X milliseconds or any other capture solutions fast enough?

Answer (score 0):

using this code as a base will help you getting a high performance. You can always play with the time in `waitKey()` but a 0 parameter will lead to an error.

```
VideoCapture capture(filename);
Mat frame;

if( !capture.isOpened() )
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";

//namedWindow( "w", 1);
for(;;)
{
    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty())
        break;
    waitKey(20); // waits to display frame
}
```